# Find the last occurrence of string and print everything beneath sed awk grep In BASH

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

Hi I have a large file that keeps getting updated quickly. It stores a lot of FIX-ORDER messages. Each order is contained in a section starting with word "FIXES" and end with word "Committed" . Within each order section the fix messages are in the first part followed by other messages in second part.
Please see sample of input and sample of output below.

In short I like to grep the file and print the last order section line by line
and make sure that the fix messages are also printed on individual lines. See Part II section below which is the final out put I need.

Please let me know if you can help

Starting text in order section ( lets call it orderA)

```
FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON:
```

FIX MESSAGE SECTION

```
FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON: 8=FIX.4.2;9=0;35=D;10=100; (Client.123.600)
```

Fix Message section + rest of log messages until we reach word Commit
please note each line ends with closed Parenthesis

```
FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON: 8=FIX.4.2;9=0;35=D;10=100; (Client.123.600)
1234  abcdefg EFG/HIT [12355] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
1235  cdghhhh ggg/HIT [19889] INFO JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Found.c.t)
1236  abwwwfg EFG/HIT [12885] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
Committed
```

What I like to do if possible using one command line only; there are two parts to the output. Pleas read  both parts before answering:

Part I) I like to use a command to grep out each order section from the line starting   with "FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON:" to the word Committed, so basically

```
FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON: 8=FIX.4.2;9=0;35=D;10=100; (Client.123.600)
1234  abcdefg EFG/HIT [12355] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
1235  cdghhhh ggg/HIT [19889] INFO JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Found.c.t)
1234  abcdefg EFG/HIT [12355] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
Committed
```

Part II)

```
 I like to print each Fix message that is divided by ";" in a new line 
 please note that the last entry of the fix message is (Client.123.600)
 so my final out put should look like this

FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON: 
8=FIX.4.2;
9=0;35=D;
10=100; 
(Client.123.600)
1234  abcdefg EFG/HIT [12355] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
1235  cdghhhh ggg/HIT [19889] INFO JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Found.c.t)
1234  abcdefg EFG/HIT [12355] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
Committed
```

Comment: you have plenty of `orders` in the question without showing a good complete input sample and nothing at all to your own efforts to solve it

Comment: Have a wonderful day !!

Answer (score 1):

Modified as shown below :

```
tac <data_file> | sed -n -e '/Committed/,/FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON/p ; /FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON/q' | tac | sed -e '/Client/ { s/:\s?/:\n/g ; s/;\s*/;\n/g }'
```

Comment: This command partially works. It print the output twice ? Not sure why? Also   I need to look for the last occurrence of the FIXES? Not sure how your script does that? It seems it look for the first one in the file?

Comment: hi Ed .. I tried and tried I still get the same . It prints the results twice .. Not sure why .. Let me know if you could provide a little input and perhaps if you  have time to explain the command in detail I can figure it out on my own?

Comment: I was able to get the last occurrence of the output, so now all is left to do is to break up the fix messages into different lines

Comment: I did not realize you wanted only the last occurrence. Sorry, missed that one. I have modified it ; not very pretty though. Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ last_entry_line=$(grep -n '^FIXES ' test.txt | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1 )
$ cat test.txt | sed -n "${last_entry_line},/Committ/p" | sed '/^FIXES/s/\([:;]\)\s*/\1;\n/g'
```

To make the critics happy, I will explain.

In the first command, `grep -n '^FIXES '` looks for all the lines that start with 'FIXES ' and gives us the line numbers, the `tail -1` part gives us only the last one, and `cut -d: -f1` parses out the line number.

In the second command, `sed -n` does not print anything unless we send it a "print" command.  Our "print" command tells `sed` to print from the line number we found to the next instance of "Committed".  We send those lines to another `sed` which replaces colons and semicolons (followed by any amount of whitespace) with a colon or semicolon (whichever we found) and a newline character.

Comment: Explanation is always helpful to increase the long term value of any answer.

Comment: Hi Thx for ur reply. The command does not work. I tried even portion by portion,  The files is large and contains many entries. I need to get the last entry in the file, which your command does not take into account ? Unless I am wrong it looks for the first occurrence of the Fixes? am I wrong please tell me ? Again, not sure why the first portion of the command does not work ? I mean sed -n '/^FIXES/,/Committ/p'

Comment: I'm sorry -- missed that "last entry" part.  Will fix answer.

Comment: Thanks Jack very kind of you, Looking forward to see the revised

Comment: Will give this a go jack. I am trying to look for tac command that does the same thing looking so far it's not working. I let u know

Comment: Using tac allows u to reverse the file around and then do the search like that

Comment: The first line of your command does not work ,, I am trying to see how I can get the last line number

Comment: Works for me.  When you say it does not work, are you getting the wrong line?  Are you getting nothing at all?

Comment: I used the following for the first line  awk '/FIXES /{print NR}' filename | tail -1  .. not sure why the first line was not working . .I will try the rest of ur command now

Comment: i tried second portion if ur command and it does not produce the desired output. it just prints the line as is

Comment: Sounds like you have some really basic things that are not working on your system.  What system ARE you on, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
inMsgs {
    # Previous line must have been a FIXES.. line and we are
    # now in the messages lines so just append each of them
    # to the msgs variable as they are read.
    msgs = msgs $0 ORS
}
/Committed/ {
    # Found a "Committed" line so this is the end of a complete
    # block of input so save the contents of the current "fix"
    # and "msgs" variables to the "last read block" equivalents
    # and clear the "in messages block" flag.
    lastFix  = fix
    lastMsgs = msgs
    inMsgs   = 0
}
/^FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON:/ {
    # Found a FIXES... line so save that "fix" line, empty
    # the buffer of "msgs" and set the "in messages block flag"
    # so it is set when the next line is read.
    fix      = $0
    msgs     = ""
    inMsgs   = 1
}
END {
    # We have reached the end of the input file so insert newlines
    # where appropriate in the "lastFix" line then print it and
    # then print the lines stored in the "lastMsgs" variable.
    print gensub(/([^:]+:) ([^;]+;)([^;]+;)([^;]+;)([^;]+;) (.*)/,"\\1\n\\2\n\\3\n\\4\n\\5\n\\6",1,lastFix)
    printf "%s", lastMsgs
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON:
8=FIX.4.2;
9=0;
35=D;
10=100;
(Client.123.600)
1234  abcdefg EFG/HIT [12355] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
1235  cdghhhh ggg/HIT [19889] INFO JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Found.c.t)
1236  abwwwfg EFG/HIT [12885] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
Committed
```

Most of the complexity is to ensure it only prints the last **complete** record (i.e. one that ends with "Committed").

Here's a better sample input file to demonstrate why the above logic is necessary:

```
$ cat file
stuff
FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON: 8=FIX.4.2;9=0;35=D;10=100; (Client.123.600)
1231  abcdefg EFG/HIT [12355] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
1232  cdghhhh ggg/HIT [19889] INFO JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Found.c.t)
1233  abwwwfg EFG/HIT [12885] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
Committed
foo
FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON: 8=FIX.4.2;9=0;35=D;10=100; (Client.123.600)
1234  abcdefg EFG/HIT [12355] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
1235  cdghhhh ggg/HIT [19889] INFO JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Found.c.t)
1236  abwwwfg EFG/HIT [12885] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
Committed
bar
FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON: 8=FIX.4.2;9=0;35=D;10=100; (Client.123.600)
1237  abcdefg EFG/HIT [12355] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
1238  cdghhhh ggg/HIT [19889] INFO JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Found.c.t)
1239  abwwwfg EFG/HIT [12885] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
```

In the above case the expected output would be the middle block (the one with message lines starting 1234, 1235, and 1236) , not the last block because the last block doesn't end with `Committed` and so is still in the process of being written to the input file by whatever command is generating it. The last **complete** block in the file is therefore the middle one and so the expected output is as produced by the above awk command:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
FIXES LIMIT CHECK ON:
8=FIX.4.2;
9=0;
35=D;
10=100;
(Client.123.600)
1234  abcdefg EFG/HIT [12355] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
1235  cdghhhh ggg/HIT [19889] INFO JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Found.c.t)
1236  abwwwfg EFG/HIT [12885] debug JUN 20 17:25:34 Matched  (Match.c.t)
Committed
```

Comment: Hi Ed .. I am going t ogive this a go, Thx , But looks very complex and don't understand how it works ,

Comment: As I mentioned, requiring only the last complete block to be printed does introduce some complexity as you need to make sure you find the last block of text that starts with FIXES but only overwrite the previous such block if the current one ends with Committed as THAT would be the last complete block in the file even though there's a FIXES line after it. But, each code segment is simple on it's own. I added better sample input that shows why you need the code I posted and I added comments to each code block. The posted sed+other-tools solutions will fail given that input and have other issues